# Redirection after registration

Tags: user-registration, wp-redirect

I need to redirect a newly registered user to a certain page. I customize the template page with some custom code. this code was working fine, but recently this code stopped to works after I shifted my website to another hosting provider. this is the code

```
<?php

$redirect_url = get_site_url();

if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    $lms_settings = get_option('stm_lms_settings', array());
    $user_url = (!empty($lms_settings['user_url'])) ? $lms_settings['user_url'] : '/lms-user';
    $redirect_url .= $user_url . '/' .  get_current_user_id();
}

$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id=$user_id )->data;
$user_registered = $user_data->user_registered;
if( time()-strtotime($user_registered) < 30 ){
    $redirect_url = get_site_url();
    $redirect_url .= '/apply-as-a-vendor/';
    wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
}
wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
```

if I comment out/remove the 3rd line's condition then this code can redirect, but then it redirects after login also. But I want to redirect only for first time registration. Regards Sumon

Comment: Where exactly have you put this? One of the template files in your theme?

Comment: You could save 'have_shown_apply_as_vendor' as a flag in usermeta, although it would be worth checking that doesn't cause an extra database request on every page load. Otherwise you'll need to debug why `time()-strtotime($user_registered)` isn't working as you expect. It may be e.g. that the registration time is being generated with the database server's clock which is different to the web server's clock, but I don't know that code well enough to say.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, yes I put this code on the plugins template page.